# In the JDK 1.8 source code, why use A-B> 0 to determine which one is larger, not A> B?

Tags: java, java-8

As a beginner, I read the source code of JDK1.8 recently. I faced the question that why use A-B> 0 to determine which one is larger, not A> B?

The code of below is in java/util/ArrayList.java:236

```java
private void ensureExplicitCapacity(int minCapacity) {
    modCount++;

    // overflow-conscious code
    if (minCapacity - elementData.length > 0)
        grow(minCapacity);
}
```

I can't understand the code of `minCapacity - elementData.length > 0`. Why not use minCapacity > elementData.length.

Comment: what if 'A' in this case `minCapacity` turns out to be a negative value? (overflow-conscious as the comment would possibly mean)

Comment: Note that this code is no longer there in later versions of the JDK (e.g. 17).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably to prevent [overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) of minCapacity, check this example:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int elementDataLength = 10;
    int minCapacity = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // very big

    minCapacity += 1; // accidentally overflow it

    if (minCapacity > elementDataLength) {
        System.out.println("Will not work: minCapacity=-2147483647 elementDataLength=10");
    }
    if (minCapacity - elementDataLength > 0) {
        System.out.println("Will work: minCapacity - elementDataLength = 2147483638");
    }
}
```